# Visual Studio Team Services - Relationship between git repository and solution

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have two separate applications (two Visual Studio solutions); one is a Web App while the other is a Web Service. They are going to hosted in different environments. They are related though (the web app will consume the service).

The web app is part of a `Visual Studio Team Services` Repository and uses `Git`. The service  is something that needs to be added to Version Control.

What I'd like to know is whether a new Visual Studio solution can be added to an existing repository in Visual studio Team Services (*I plan to use the same users/roles/permissions etc*)?

Also, what is the best practice in general (no change in users/roles/permissions etc.):

1. One repository having multiple Visual Studio solutions (1:n relation between repositories and solutions)
2. One repository having exactly one Visual Studio solution (1:1 relation between repositories and solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one repository per solution. You can set up multiple git repositories in one visual studio team services project, making the management of users/permissions easy. Then each solution won't have to constant merge with changes from the other in order to commit to master. In addition, if you set up autodeployment, you life will be a lot easier if you have separate repos